# Regex for removing EOL when there is no dot

Tags: php, regex

I would like to find a regex for replacing EOL by a space in a string when there is no dot at the end and keep it if there is a dot:

Should stay like that:

```
string 'extérieur et solarium.
' (length=24)
```

EOL should be replaced by a space:

```
string 'Salsomaggiore, dans des chambres de 2 à 3
' (length=43)
```

So far I found:

- how to recognize strings containing dot and \n:

  ```
    preg_match('.\.\n.', $string)
  ```
- how to replace \n by a space:

  ```
    str_replace("\n", " ", $string);
  ```

But how can I inverse first regex and mix them?
Can't find it.

Comment: What if there is `\r\n` instead of `\n` ? Try to use `\R+` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\.)\r?\n
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/eW2aX9

Comment: Becouse I didn't understand this answer too, I found this Website which may help ;-) http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @MatthiasDunkel I have clarified my anwser

Comment: Oh great! Upvoted ;-) (Off topic: How did you made the image?)